# Memory referenced by rvalue references

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

Given a function

```
int foo()
{
   return 15;
}
```

it is OK to use:

```
int&& ref = foo();
```

but not OK to use:

```
int& ref = foo();
```

which is understandable since the return value of `foo()` is an `rvalue`. However, how I am able to use the following?

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void f(T&& param)
{
   param *= 2;
}

int foo()
{
   return 15;
}

int test1()
{
   int&& ref = foo();
   std::cout << "ref = " << ref << std::endl;
   f(ref);
   std::cout << "ref = " << ref << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
   test1();
   return 0;
}
```

with the following output, which looks reasonable:

```
ref = 15
ref = 30
```

It seems that `ref` points to memory that is writeable. Does the line:

```
   int&& ref = foo();
```

allocate writeable memory for use by `ref`?

Is this standard compliant?

The code was tested using g++ 4.8.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the behavior is well-defined because by binding the return value to an rvalue reference, you've extended the lifetime of the temporary to match that of the reference it is bound to.

From *§12.2 [class.temporary]*

> *4*   There are two contexts in which temporaries are destroyed at a different point than the end of the full-expression. `...`
>   *5*   The second context is when a reference is bound to a temporary. The temporary to which the reference is bound or the temporary that is the complete object of a subobject to which the reference is bound persists for the lifetime of the reference except: 
>      `...` (list of exceptions, none of which apply to this case)

Note that the lifetime extension rule only applies to [*prvalues*, and not *xvalues*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues) (refer to *§12.2/1*). So if your example did the following, you'd have a dangling reference:

```
int&& ref = std::move(foo());
```

Comment: I take your word for it, but I haven't quite grasped the difference `std::move()` makes for `ref` to be a dangling reference.